# How to convert MS Word Smart Quotes and em-dashes to simple quotes and dashes in Ckeditor 4

Tags: html-entities, ckeditor4.x

Hi I really like the new Ckeditor 4 Advanced Content Filtering along with the pastefromword plugin - and have read the docs on what html tags to allow and not, and I understand why it kindly converts my client's MS Word crap into **htmlentities**. **However, I'd like to do a little intervention and convert the smart quotes to straight quotes - and all em dashes to plain dashes and not allow   - *before the text gets sent to the CMS database. But I can't find any docs on this or examples.***

I can see there were many questions about this on the old forum Ckeditor forum http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Replacing-smart-quotes-regular-quotes, http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Problem-copyingpasting-MS-Word but they didn't get answered.

I'm also hoping the ckeditor team reads these forums as this is where they suggest we post questions now.

Answer (score 5):

CKEditor dev here.

If you want the Paste From Word plugin to do this, you could add a rule in the plugin that replaces the contents of text nodes.

To achieve this add a property named 'text' somewhere over here(on the same level as the 'comment' property):
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/pastefromword/filter/default.js#L1106

It should be a function that accepts one parameter - the text node content, e.g.:

```
text: function( content ) {
    return content.replace(/[\u201E\u201C]/g,'"'); // Unicode for &bdquo; and &ldquo;
}
```

This way whenever the PFW plugin filter encounters a text node it'll replace its contents with whatever is returned by the above mentioned function.

Caveats: there are *quite a few* Unicode symbols that represent quotation marks and dashes.

By the way: you may not want to get too attached to the current Paste From Word plugin - we're planning a major refactor of it for v4.6.

I hope this was helpful.